# AG Grid: Changing visual appearance of editable cells

Tags: ag-grid

What is the best practice to inform a user of Ag grid if a cell is editable or not visually?

Is it possible to change visual appearance of an editable cell in ag grid globally, like how it is done here. For partially editable cells there is a border around the value?
Or can we have a cell in always editable mode in ag grid?

Image courtesy: https://design.gs.com/components/grid
[image]